# pandas not able to install python 3.6.9

Tags: python, pandas

I have below installed packages

```
asn1crypto       0.24.0
asyncio          3.4.3
beautifulsoup4   4.7.1
boto             2.49.0
boto3            1.9.199
botocore         1.12.199
certifi          2019.6.16
cffi             1.12.3
chardet          3.0.4
configparser     5.0.1
cryptography     2.7
cx-Oracle        6.4.1
docutils         0.14
gensim           3.5.0
idna             2.8
jmespath         0.9.4
joblib           0.13.2
lxml             4.3.4
nltk             3.3
pid              3.0.4
pip              20.0.2
psutil           5.7.2
pycparser        2.19
python-dateutil  2.8.0
python-pidfile   3.0.0
requests         2.22.0
s3transfer       0.2.1
setuptools       40.6.2
six              1.12.0
smart-open       1.8.4
sortedcontainers 2.1.0
soupsieve        1.9.3
statistics       1.0.3.5
urllib3          1.25.3
```

When I tried to install pandas 1.1.0 for python 3.6.9

```
python3.6 -m  pip install --proxy=https://abcd.com --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org  pandas==1.1.0 -i https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas==1.1.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==1.1.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

**I have tried without any version of pandas but no luck still same error**

```
--install-option.
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Please help me

Comment: Can you try just a simple python3.6 -m pip install pandas==1.1.0?

Comment: yes I tried without proxy it gave below error ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/a7/f7/2adca20a7fa71b6a32f823bbd83992adeceab1d8bf72992bb7a55c69c19a/pandas-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))

Comment: with proxy also failed due to certificate

Comment: Have you tried upgrading pip first?

Comment: I'm surprised that you want to install 1.1.0, and not 1.1.5, which has the same feature set, but with added bug- and security fixes.

Comment: I have tried upgrade as python3.6 only support 20.3 pip

Comment: I tried without any pandas version still not work please check updated post any version I can install

Comment: I think Python 3.6 will support pip 21.3.1. Why do you claim otherwise?

Comment: The current pip version may indeed not support Python 3.6, although the [PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/pip/21.3.1/) still claims support for Python 3.6 with pip 21.3.1. But you should still be able to upgrade pip to a more recent version than 20.3, which may resolve your SSL issues.

Comment: How did you install python? what system are you using? I'm asking because if you tried to build it yourself (for a raspberry Pi or etc) you might have the SSL issues mentioned.